# Php don't print if line begins with

Tags: php

I have the below code which prints out lines of text as long as the lines aren't empty:

```
$textChunk = wordwrap($value, 35, "\n");
    foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine)
    {
        if ($textLine!=='') 
        {
            $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 75, $line, 'UTF-8');
            $line -=14;
        }
    }
```

I would like to edit it so that it also doesn't print the line if it begins with 'T:'

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean if it is *either* blank or starts with "T:"? Or only "T:"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [substr](http://php.net/substr) to check the first two characters:

```
if ($textLine !== '' && substr($textline, 0, 2) !== 'T:')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strpos()` looking for "T:" in the `0` position:

```
$textChunk = wordwrap($value, 35, "\n");
foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine)
{
    // Don't print if T: is at the 0 position
    if (strpos($textLine, "T:") > 0) 
    {
        $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 75, $line, 'UTF-8');
        $line -=14;
    }
}
```

If you still need to filter the blanks as well, use:

```
        if ($textLine !== "" || strpos($textLine, "T:") > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$textChunk = wordwrap($value, 35, "\n");
foreach(array_filter(explode("\n", $textChunk)) as $textLine)
{
    if (strncmp('T:', $textLine,2) !== 0)
    {
        $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 75, $line, 'UTF-8');
        $line -=14;
    }
}
```

At all `strncmp()` is slightly faster than `substr()`.

Answer (score 0):

I often find myself writing such functions to deal with starting/ending of strings

```
function stringStartsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    return $needle === substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle));
 }

function stringEndsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    return $needle === substr($haystack,-1 *strlen($needle));
}
```

Then you could use

```
if (textLine && ! stringStartsWith($textLine,'T:')
```